# Parsing error: Unexpected token as. How can I use typescript specifying types inside template tags

Tags: typescript, vue.js, pug, vite, volar

I use `pug` inside my Vue `<template>`, it's syntax erorr for me on console：

temp.vue:

```js
<template lang="pug">
p {{ directions[directionName as keyof typeof directions] }}
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  props: ["directionName"],
  setup() {
    enum directions {
      Left = "L",
      Right = "R",
      Up = "U",
      Down = "D",
    }

    return {
      directions
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

error:

```
vue-router.esm-bundler.js:3325 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'as' (at ...)
```

Dependencies：

- vite: `^3.1.8`
- vue: `^3.2.25`
- pug: `^3.0.2`
- @volar/vue-language-plugin-pug: `^1.0.9`
- typescript: `~4.5.5`
- vite-plugin-pug: `^0.3.1`
- vue-tsc: `^1.0.9`

how can I typecasting inside the `<template>` tags?